# Does "Stash pullrequest builder plugin" for Jenkins supports single pull request building?

Tags: java, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket-server

If you, provide, please, an example.
I tried to use non-plugin parameter Refspec:

```
+refs/pull-requests/$PULL_REQUEST_ID/from:pull/$PULL_REQUEST_ID
```

But without a successful result.

Comment: You question is not clear (sorry). How do you want to trigger your Jenkins job regarding the Stash pull request? I don't understand if you want to trigger only some kind of PR.

Comment: As I said, I want manually trigger build for one pull request (by ID).